# is it possible to get all source from tag to working copy and then commit to trunk?

Tags: svn, tags, trunk

in svn, my working copy is connected to trunk, now I want get all thing from a version in tag and replace all the thing in my working copy, but after the replace, I want I get commit back to trunk, but not tag, is it possible?

I found that if the source of working copy is get from tag, then it can only commit back to tag, but not trunk.

I am using subclipse version 1.8.8

Comment: So you want to replace 'trunk' with what's currently in the tag?

Comment: yes, exactly, and after the replace, I can still commit back to trunk, but not tag.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991344/merging-from-branch-to-trunk-with-merge-range-of-revisions). Just replace the word `branch` with `tag` when you read it.

Comment: no, I want completely replace the trunk content with tag, but not merge

Answer (score 0):

1. svn merge trunk tag .
2. you need to resolve conflicts if has any
3. svn diff
4. svn commit

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the trunk directory from the repository
2. Rename the tag directory to "trunk"

Alternatively, you could:

1. check out trunk to directory A.
2. check out tag to directory B.
3. Delete the entire contents of A except for the .svn directory or directories. (In older versions there is an .svn subdirectory in every directory; in newer versions there is just one .svn directory at the top of the checkout.)
4. Copy the entire contents of B to A, except for any .svn directories.
5. Commit A to trunk.

Depending on what you use for your client-side SVN, you may need to do explicit "adds" for any new files or direrctories. Command-line SVN makes you do individual add commands. Tortoise tells you what the adds and deletes are and you can just click boxes. I think Eclipse handles the adds and deletes automatically. (Just 7 months since I used Eclipse and already I'm forgetting the details.)

Answer (score 0):

```
svn move $repo/trunk $repo/old-trunk
svn move $repo/tags/1.2.3.4 $repo/trunk
```